# John has been doing work. Work has been being done by John

Tags: active-voice

John has been doing work. Work has been being done by John. 
Can we make the passive of Present perfect Continuous tense? 
I read in different books that we can not make?

Comment: The construction is grammatically valid, makes perfect sense when read and parsed carefully, but has practically no use in general English writing. HTH.

Comment: Can you cite the sources that mention the argument?

Comment: @Kris: I think it's this: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html

Comment: @AishwaryaAR No, I meant the source that says "we **cannot** make the passive of present perfect continuous tense."

Comment: Oh, okay! 'the argument'!

Comment: [Addressed before.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244901/whats-with-the-passive-present-perfect-progressive)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1 Right find. Yet to see if that has a good answer and thus this could be a dupe. Maybe.

Comment: [When should one use Present Perfect Continuous Passive?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/when-should-one-use-present-perfect-continuous-passive) and [Can the present perfect continuous construct be used in passive voice?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/can-the-present-perfect-continuous-construct-be-used-in-passive-voice)

Comment: OP may need to do some research right on this site first. Else it would be GR.

Comment: This question highlights a problem which often arises when looking at acceptability of usages. _Work has been being done by John_ sounds outlandish to my ears, but _The work on the new program has been being done by John, Ali and Sue_ perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

"Work **has been** being done by John" is invalid: the "has been" implies that the work is finished, the "being" implies that it's not finished, and so it would be self-contradictory.

You can say "Work **is being** done by John" (it's still happening), or "Work **was being** done by John" (it was happening but is no longer happening.)

Comment: But, I used Google,there was written these sentences correctly.

Comment: These sentences were written correctly. Can we make  present perfect Continuous tense passive sentences? I was confused 1st. Later on,  I took guidance from Google.

Comment: Yes I see: you find it used as an example on this page: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html Nevertheless IMO (and I may be wrong) I can't make sense of the phrase.

Comment: Why is it invalid?

Comment: Hi, These are not written in certified books.Suuh as, Wren&Martin, Oxford Practical Grammar etc.

Comment: @Kris Because if it's still happening or no longer happening, why wouldn't you say "is being" or "was being" instead? Because it's not used colloquially. Because it's "invalid" in the same sort of way that a "small red house" is correct but a "red small house" is incorrect i.e. it sounds wrong.

Comment: @Kris Isn't the point that it is mixing tenses. "I have continue to work."

Comment: @Avon Please see the above comment.

Comment: It's not "invalid" just extremely rare, and as Kris implied, impractical in the real world. *This book has been being written by two authors*, (two authors have been writing this book) whereas *"This book has been written by two authors"* (two authors have written this book) is easier to comprehend, and means more or less the same thing.

Comment: 'the "has been" implies that the work is finished' shows a lack of understanding. 'He has been digging for two hours now [and needs to take a rest soon].'

Comment: @Kris I'm sorry but I don't think I should be expected to parse sentences one word at a time. If a non-native-English speaker gives me that sentence, then I'll accept and more-or-less understand it, but I'll note it as non-idiomatic.

Comment: As far as grammar is concerned, the sentence follows the standard structure for the present perfect continuous in passive equivalent. Looked that way, it is comprehensible and conveys exactly the same meaning as its active voice counterpart.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for the example. I now see where Kris has been coming from. My issue is that I think in the first example you give the tense of "writing" is helpfully ambiguous making the past tense of "has been" fine. And the same goes for "coming" in my second sentence here.

Comment: @Kris You might argue the same about "small red house" and "red small house" (that they're both 'standard structure', depending on how you define your 'standards'), yet one is used and other sounds like English-as-a-second-language.

Comment: These issues are not really related at all. Multiple adjectives generally follow a (recommended) **hierarchial** order. See related posts on this site.

Comment: @Kris I know they (adjectives) do: and I was quite surprised (a long while ago) to find that hierarchy being taught as an explicit ESL rule, because as a native-English speaker I hadn't even realized that there was such a rule (instead I just did it automatically).

Comment: @user124234 How are we to understand '_certified books_ Such as, Wren & Martin, Oxford Practical Grammar'? People have been known to query CGEL and certainly ACGEL here.  McCawley's grammar seems near unassailable.

Comment: There's no binding "rule" *per se*, you could call it a convention that the ear has been accustomed to :)

Comment: @Kris The hierarchy is different in French (you should say "une petite maison rouge"): again that's not a rule I've learned (though someone has presumably codified it somewhere), you learn that's the way people do or don't talk. If I hear "Work has been being done by John" then I'm, like, "What?"

Answer (score -1):

Both the sentences are in Present Perfect Continuous tense.Only problem is that 'point' or 'period' of time is necessary to make these sentences meaningful;otherwise, only present continuous will suffice.
Grammatically both are correct and make sense but for that time element.